# Connecting FLEX 3.0, JAVA WITH MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, apache-flex

1. How to connect to MYSQL DB from Java, create table, insert data, retrieve it with datatypes.
2. How to make use of the data to/from in Flex application.
   plz help me out..
   i have basic knowledge in sending and receiving messages using BlazeDS.
   and calling  JAVA METHODS USING  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few links to get you started:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/blazeds_spring.html

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Spring_and_Hibernate_with_BlazeDS-7923.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_hibernate.html

http://welford-costelloe.com/modules/wordpress/?p=8

And once you have more specific question, come back and ask it :-)